# Extracting an integer from a string?

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I extract the numbers out of a string like this:

```
$1.50
```

Everything but the currency symbol. Or from something like this:

```
rofl1.50lmao
```

Just asking if there's an existing function that I'm not a aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "plain" JavaScript, but FWIW:

```
justNumsAndDots = "rofl1.50lmao".replace(/[^\d.]/g,"") // -> "1.50" (string)
asIntegral = parseInt("0" + justNumsAndDots, 10)       // -> 1 (number)
asNumber = parseFloat("0" + justNumsAndDots)           // -> 1.5 (number)
asTwoDecimalPlaces = (2 + asNumber).toFixed(2)         // -> "3.50" (string)
```

Notes:

1. Doesn't take localization into account.
2. Radix (base-10) is passed to parseInt to avoid potential octal conversion (not sure if this "issue" plagues AS).
3. "0" is added to the start of justNumsAndDots so parseInt/parseFloat will never return a NaN here. (e.g. `parseFloat(".") -> NaN`, `parseFloat("0.") -> 0`). If NaN's are desired, alter to suite.
4. Input like "rofl1.chopter50lolz" will be stripped to "1.50", it might be over-greedy, depending.
5. Adapt to AS as necessary.

Happy coding.

Comment: Your call to `replace` has a major fault in it.  Try the string `"w10w10w.w10"` to see what I mean.  You should say this instead: `replace(/^\D*/g, "")`.  The uncut noise after the number will be ignored by the parse functions.

Comment: For my purposes this works perfectly, since the user won't be able to play around with the signs, and isn't allowed to input letters or special characters besides a dot.

Answer (score 4):

There is no builtin function in AS3 for that. A simple RegExp like this one should help you :

```
/[0-9]+.?[0-9]*/
```

This is an example, and should be refactored depending your context.

Here is a more precise RegEx from [Gunslinger47](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179984/gunslinger47):

```
/-?\d*\.?\d+([eE]\d+)?/
```

Comment: For implementation's sake, `str = str.match(/[0-9]+.?[0-9]*/g).toString();`.

Comment: @OXMO456 +1 for showing a specific-match approach (I'm assuming the problems in the post will be fixed ;-). However, this will fail to match ".123" and will match "123_456" and the use of `/g` is suspect as it then opens it up to match "1.2 blah blah blah 1.4" (will result in "1.2,1.4" after string-ification and thus is "useless" for this task). Also, `[0-9]` is more cleanly written as `\d`, IMOHO

Comment: @pst yes, this is not the 'perfect' regex but it's a start ; ) it could be refactored depending on the context and needs !

Comment: @pst i agree with you, but the question is already marked as answered so... thank for the +1 btw : )

Comment: `/-?\d*\.?\d+([eE]\d+)?/` may be better.  It catches `.123`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no. You can parse every character against an array of valid characters, or use regexp.